# Is there any evidence that Google randomizes the SERP results for equivalent domains?

Tags: google-search, google-ranking

I realize that there's been a lot of apparent Google fluctuations over the past few months.

However, to me, it looks as though Google might be randomly ordering positions 3-10 in my particular niche among similar quality domains.  I'm curious, is there any evidence or prior statements from Google that might indicate this is true?  Or, should I simply interpret this as just multiple updates from Google and within my competitors?

Comment: "equivalent domains" - what do you mean exactly by this? No two search results are ever exactly equal (and there is no way you can determine this anyway as a Google outsider), particularly when dealing with "my competitors" (presumably sites out of your control). I can't think of any possible reason why Google would ever "randomize" the SERPs - that would seem to make no sense at all?! Any changes in the SERPs will no doubt be down to changes in on/off site SEO between the sites and possibly algorithm changes at Google.

Comment: @DocRoot I realize that it may be rare, if ever.  I assume that every URL has some weight assigned to it by Google, and that Google sorts the SERPs by this weight.  Should I assume no two URLs ever have exactly the same weight?  Even random number generators are known for generating potential duplicates.